# outmemoryerror saving hdfs streaming proccess spark python

Tags: python, hadoop, out-of-memory, hdfs, spark-streaming

We have an application developed in python with spark streaming (version 1.6) that executes a kafka process reading, clears the information and inserts this new information into the elastic Search and HDFS.

The process works well for 1 hour, but after this we are experiencing the following exception:

```
     self._jwrite.save(path)
  File "/tmp/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/u028952/appcache/application_1510909047380_0215/container_e02_1510909047380_0215_01_000002/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 813, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/tmp/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/u028952/appcache/application_1510909047380_0215/container_e02_1510909047380_0215_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 45, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/tmp/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/u028952/appcache/application_1510909047380_0215/container_e02_1510909047380_0215_01_000002/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25359.save.
: java.io.IOException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: unexpected checked exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufHelper.getRemoteException(ProtobufHelper.java:47)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.delete(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:542)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor77.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:252)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:104)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.delete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.delete(DFSClient.java:2052)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$14.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$14.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:713)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.delete(DistributedFileSystem.java:713)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.cleanupJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.abortJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:529)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.BaseWriterContainer.abortJob(WriterContainer.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:139)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor92.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException: java.lang.RuntimeException: unexpected checked exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:243)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.delete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.delete(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:540)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: unexpected checked exception
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.sendRpcRequest(Client.java:1066)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
    at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:658)
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311)
    at sun.nio.ch.Util.getTemporaryDirectBuffer(Util.java:174)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:58)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream$Writer.performIO(SocketOutputStream.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.doIO(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:117)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection$3.run(Client.java:1041)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more


    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.callPythonTransformFunction(PythonDStream.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.TransformFunction.apply(PythonDStream.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonDStream$$anonfun$callForeachRDD$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.python.PythonDStream$$anonfun$callForeachRDD$1.apply(PythonDStream.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

We are running the job in cluster mode and parallelazing the execution without problems. We are saving in hdfs, I doint know if parquet format that could also be the problem.

```
path = ("hdfs://" + host + ":" + port + path + date)

#Storing in parquet format allows to appending to a folder
df.write.format("parquet").mode("append").save(path)
```

Any suggestion will be fine.
Thanks in advance.